# How to iterate through dict with multiple columns in PL/SQL to take values from it and inject them into where statement in query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got problem as follows:
In oracle database I would like to run query which iterate through some kind of dictionary and take values from it to fill in where statement in query and return set of records for each single query, meaning if dict has 3 rows it should return three sets of record and union them afterwards. I have following tables:

dict(table)

```
country | filter_value
US      |      y
GE      |      N
UK      |      Y,N
```

data(table 1)

```
seller_id  |  country |     flag | type
   1       |  US      |      y   |   w
   2       |  US      |      n   |   w 
   3       |  GE      |      y   |   w
   4       |  GE      |      n   |   w
   5       |  UK      |      y   |   w
   6       |  UK      |      n   |   w 
   7       |  PT      |      y   |   w
   8       |  GR      |      n   |   w
```

data(table 2)

```
seller_id   |  country |     flag | type
   19       |  US      |      y   |   d
   28       |  US      |      n   |   d 
   33       |  GE      |      y   |   d
   44       |  GE      |      n   |   d
   54       |  UK      |      y   |   d
   66       |  UK      |      n   |   d 
   71       |  PT      |      y   |   d
   82       |  GR      |      n   |   d
```

and I would like to run something like this:

```
union_data=empty table
for row in dict:
    select * from data(table1) where country=row.country and flag in (row.filter_value)
    select * from data(table2) where country=row.country and flag in (row.filter_value)
    union results from this both queries is one table meaning this union_data
```

I'm completely new in PL/SQL and to be honest don't know which functionality would work out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two options.

The first one is simpler and looks like this: create a function (returns a refcursor) which accepts `country`, finds filter value and applies both "parameters" to `select` statement(s):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_country in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_filter_value dict.filter_value%type;
  5    l_rc           sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select filter_value
  8      into l_filter_value
  9      from dict
 10      where country = par_country;
 11
 12    open l_rc for
 13      select seller_id, country, flag, type
 14        from data
 15        where country = par_country
 16          and flag = l_filter_value
 17      union all
 18      select seller_id, country, flag, type
 19        from data2
 20        where country = par_country
 21          and flag = l_filter_value;
 22
 23    return l_rc;
 24  end;
 25  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('US') from dual;

F_TEST('US')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

 SELLER_ID COUNTRY    FLAG TYPE
---------- ---------- ---- ----
         1 US         Y    W
        19 US         Y    D


SQL>
```

---

If that's too simple (meaning: you can't/don't want to do it that way), use dynamic SQL. The principle is similar to previous. This example includes "what if `DICT` table contains both `Y,N` in `filter_value`" - in that case, split fetched `filter_value` to rows (that's what hierarchical subqueries do).

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_country in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_filter_value dict.filter_value%type;
  5    l_rc           sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select filter_value
  8      into l_filter_value
  9      from dict
 10      where country = par_country;
 11
 12    open l_rc for
 13      select seller_id, country, flag, type
 14        from data
 15        where country = par_country
 16          and flag in (select regexp_substr(l_filter_value, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 17                       from dual
 18                       connect by level <= regexp_count(l_filter_value, ',') + 1
 19                      )
 20      union all
 21      select seller_id, country, flag, type
 22        from data2
 23        where country = par_country
 24          and flag in (select regexp_substr(l_filter_value, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 25                       from dual
 26                       connect by level <= regexp_count(l_filter_value, ',') + 1
 27                      );
 28
 29    return l_rc;
 30  end;
 31  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('US') from dual;

F_TEST('US')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

 SELLER_ID COUNTRY    FLAG TYPE
---------- ---------- ---- ----
         1 US         Y    W
        19 US         Y    D


SQL> select f_test('UK') from dual;

F_TEST('UK')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

 SELLER_ID COUNTRY    FLAG TYPE
---------- ---------- ---- ----
         5 UK         Y    W
         6 UK         N    W
        54 UK         Y    D
        66 UK         N    D


SQL>
```

Comment: One question. How to change this function in case the dict has two separate rows for UK I.e. UK      |      y and the second UK      |      n? When I tried this in cursor I received only rows which fitted the last value meaning with flag=n

Comment: I edited my 2nd example to cover this situation. Have a look, please.